# How to represent byte and word (int16) in protobuf .proto file?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have some binary data in the follow structure:

- signature: 2 bytes
- length: 2 bytes
- version: 1 byte
- serial: 1 byte
- command: 2 bytes
- data: bytes[]
- checksum: byte

So, how can I write the .proto file for these?

Comment: Did Google REALLY provide no clues?

Comment: Int, basically. Signed or unsigned to match your data. It will be "varint" encoded, so it'll take one byte per 7 bits, based on the largest bit set in the value.